# How to delete controller in Laravel 10 using command line

Tags: laravel, command-line-interface

I have created controller in laravel using command `php artisan make:controller AuthLoginRegisterClass`

Now, I want to delete it using only command line, can you please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: If you run php artisan make:controller -h you will see all the available options. There is no artisan command to delete the controller, unless you create your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the power of shell script to delete the file using terminal. I created a script to delete the file in controllers folder. It will search for the file inside the `Controllers` folder and delete it once it finds it. Here's the script:

###### delete.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=$1

# Find the file in the Controllers directory
FILE_PATH=$(find ./app/Http/Controllers -name "$FILE_NAME" -type f -print -quit)

# Check if the file exists
if [ -n "$FILE_PATH" ]; then
    # Remove the file
    rm "$FILE_PATH"

    echo "File deleted successfully."
else
    echo "File not found."
fi
```

You can give this file appropriate permissions i.e. `executable` with `chmod +x delete.sh` and use it with the following command:

`./delete.sh FooBarController.sh`

Hope this helps in resolving the issue.

Edit:

You can create a command with `php artisan make:command FooCommand` and add the following code in the FooCommand.php file:

```
protected $signature = 'controller:delete {name : The name of the controller file to be deleted}';
    
        protected $description = 'Delete a controller file';
    
        public function handle()
        {
            $controllerName = $this->argument('name');
            $controllerPath = app_path("Http/Controllers/{$controllerName}.php");
    
            if (File::exists($controllerPath)) {
                File::delete($controllerPath);
                $this->info("Controller file '{$controllerName}' deleted successfully.");
            } else {
                $this->error("Controller file '{$controllerName}' not found.");
            }
        }
```

Your file will look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class DeleteControllerFile extends Command
{
   protected $signature = 'controller:delete {name : The name of the controller file to be deleted}';

    protected $description = 'Delete a controller file';

    public function handle()
    {
        $controllerName = $this->argument('name');
        $controllerPath = app_path("Http/Controllers/{$controllerName}.php");

        if (File::exists($controllerPath)) {
            File::delete($controllerPath);
            $this->info("Controller file '{$controllerName}' deleted successfully.");
        } else {
            $this->error("Controller file '{$controllerName}' not found.");
        }
    }        
}
```

Now you can also use `php artisan controller:delete foobarController` to delete the file with php artisan command.

Comment: But I need to delete that file using php artisan command? from command line I know how to delete

Comment: @Hassan Ali , I have done same way but when I fire command that time it says "name" argument does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by running the following command

```
rm app/Http/Controllers/AuthLoginRegisterClass.php
```

Comment: But I need to delete that file using php artisan command? from command line I know how to delete

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, open the command prompt and navigate to the root directory of your Laravel project-

```
cd /path/to/your/Laravel/project
```

Now, use the 'rm' command followed by the path to the controller like-

```
rm app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php
```

(if your file is located in the app/Http/Controllers)
after executing this command the controller file will be permanently deleted from your project.

Comment: But I need to delete that file using php artisan command? from command line I know how to delete

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Hassaan's command will work, I think the easiest solution is to just create a new Laravel command that does all the work. No need to write a shell script.

Create a new command `php artisan make:command DeleteControllerCommand`

The command should look something like this;

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class DeleteControllerCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'delete:controller {controllerName : The name of the controller you want to delete}';

    protected $description = 'Delete a controller by name';

    public function handle()
    {
        $name = $this-argument('controllerName');
        $path = app_path("Http/Controllers/{$name}.php");

        if (File::exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
            $this->info("{$name} deleted");
        } else {
            $this->error("{$name} does not exist in Http/Controllers/");
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you run `php artisan delete:controller AuthLoginRegisterClass` it will check if the controller exists and delete it if it does.

Comment: yes, I have done same way but it says controllerName not found , what should I do?

Comment: You mean it is hitting the `$this->error("{$name} does not exist in Http/Controllers/");` else statement?

Comment: No , just says "name" argument does not exist on command line

Comment: Then something must be wrong in the signature. It seems that the `controllerName` argument is not defined. How are you calling the command?